# What happens to the music I downloaded from Apple music if I can't make a payment?

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-music

I've downloaded lots of music from the Apple Music trial, what happens if after say 4 months I stop paying? Does all my music get deleted or do I get to keep it.

Comment: Not totally. I am only using the trial as an example, got an answer or just want to complain?

Comment: It's the same answer — "songs are accessible only during your Apple Music membership"